# The forgotten man

Tags: riddle

Oh, how those of great influence have fallen!

Nobleman and commoner alike use what I have concieved.
Behold my works! You are beholding my works right now as you are reading these words.
Yet, no one except a few men of the labor know who I am and what my works mean.

My death was timed unfortunate, the cause of me being forgotten. Fate had it I died in the fortnight when the man named Labor, who provided labor, died as well.

Oh, how the masses wept, nobleman and commoner alike. They wept for the man named Labor.
Yet I, whose works make the man named Labor's work possible, and the works of a thousand men more I made possible, passed with barely a single thought.

Who am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a requiem for

> [Dennis Ritchie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_Ritchie) - creator of the C language and a developer of Unix, which underpins Mac OS and iOS.

The man named Labor is

> Steve Jobs of Apple, who passed the week before Dennis Ritchie, and received greater media coverage.

Comment: ding ding! we have a winner.

Comment: @Lucas I applaud the answer (+1) but the term *fortnight* used in the question makes it highly inaccurate as it stands for 14 days not 7.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac if x happened within 7 days, it consequently also happened within 14 days. If I said ''week'' it would've been easier since all the news regarding Dennis said he died in the same week as Steve Jobs. Therefore, to put it more in a ''medieval'' line of thinking I said ''fortnight''